# SQLite exception on Windows and not Mac OSX

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, windows-vista

I'm developing from Mac OS X a java application that uses a SQLite database using JDBC driver.

The code works perfectly fine on the mac, but I can't use batch inserts using `PreparedStatement`s on my Windows box.

EDIT: this also doesn't work with simple `Statement`s that contains a single `INSERT INTO` instructions (`CREATE TABLE` works fine).

My code is basically:

Table creation:

```
    final String sql = "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " USING fts3("
            + KEY_NOM + ", "
            + KEY_PRENOM + ", "
            + KEY_ADRESSE + ", "
            + KEY_ADRESSE2 + ", "
            + KEY_ADRESSE3 + ");";

    try {
        final Statement s = mConnection.createStatement();
        s.execute(sql);
    } catch (final SQLException e) {
        L.e("Unable to create table: "+sql+"! "+e);
    }
```

`PreparedStatement` creation:

```
    String sql =
            "INSERT INTO "+TABLE_NAME
                    +" ("
                    + KEY_NOM + ", "
                    + KEY_PRENOM + ", "
                    + KEY_ADRESSE + ", "
                    + KEY_ADRESSE2 + ", "
                    + KEY_ADRESSE3 + ") "
                    + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    mConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
    final PreparedStatement prep = mConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
```

Then there is a loop that parses a CSV file, and at each line the following code is called:

```
        int i = 1;
        prep.setString(i++, ""+lawyer.nom);
        prep.setString(i++, ""+lawyer.prenom);
        prep.setString(i++, ""+lawyer.adresse);
        prep.setString(i++, ""+lawyer.adresse2);
        prep.setString(i++, ""+lawyer.adresse3);
        prep.addBatch();
```

When the parsing of the CSV file is over, the following is executed:

```
        final int[] res = prep.executeBatch();
        mConnection.setAutoCommit(true);
        for (int r: res) {
            if (r != 1) {
                L.e("Error adding entry!");
            }
        }
```

When I call `mConnection.setAutoCommit(true);`, the `INSERT`s statements are executed when it raises the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: SQL logic error or missing database
at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:288)
at org.sqlite.DB.exec(DB.java:68)
at org.sqlite.Conn.setAutoCommit(Conn.java:166)
```

Tested environments:

- MacBookAir - Mac OS 10.6 - **x64** - Java 1.6.31 - **works fine** (my development station)
- Laptop - Windows 7 - **x64** - Java 1.6.30 - **works fine**
- MacBook - Mac OS 10.5 - **x64** - Java 1.6.26 - **works fine**
- Desktop - Windows Vista - **x86** - Java 1.? - **doesn't work**
- Server - Windows Server 2003 - **unknown arch, x86 guessed** - Java 1.7 - **doesn't work**
- Desktop - Windows Seven - **x86** - Java 1.7 - **doesn't work**
- Desktop - Windows XP - **x86** - Java 1.6.31 - **doesn't work**

It seems that only x64 hosts can make this to work. The following jars are used:

- swt : included the x64 version on x64 hosts, and x86 version on x86 hosts
- [sqlitejdbc-v056](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/): apparently this is x86 and x64 compatible
- [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/): this doesn't contain native code
- iText-2.1.7 and iTextRTF: this doesn't contain native code

So maybe the JDBC SQLite driver isn't fully x86-compatible. I'll try to investigate more.

Comment: What version of SQLite are you using on each box? (`SELECT sqlite_version();`)  Also, what is the path to the database? Can you see if the `CREATE TABLE` has worked?  What happens if you leave autocommit set to `true`?

Comment: I just found out that a Mac OSX 10.5 box with java 1.5 wasn't working. The Windows boxes were using Java 1.7. I found another Windows 7 box with java 1.6 which worked. The java code was compiled on a java 1.6.31 mac os 10.6 box. I think the java version mismatch could be the issue. However the create table worked, sqlite_version is 3.7.12.1 and changes to autocommit don't fix the issue. Thank you for your input.

Comment: SQLite uses native code, so you'll need the right build to work on the platform. In particular, you might run into trouble with trying to mix 32-bit and 64-bit code. Don't know if that's the problem here though…

Comment: Yep but the JDBC provider states *pure Java, containing binaries for: Windows, Linux/x86/amd64, and Mac OS X/ppc/x86/amd64*, so I figured it was OK. I checked, the jar contains .so, .jnilib and .dll for all 3 OS, and I guess/hope that each is x86/x64 compatible. I'll have to check more, but right now the only x86 box I can test on has java 1.5, and my code is compiled against java 1.6.

Comment: OK I thought the 10.5 mac was a x86 processor but it's a x64, and by running my software with a JRE 1.6 it works. So far, I couldn't make an x86 box to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*TL;DR*:
my SQLite JDBC driver was using native code and was not fully compatible with 32 bits processors.

Two possible fixes:

- Use [Xerial](http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC), a native SQLite JDBC driver that works fine on both Mac OS X 64 bits and Windows 32 bits
- Use a pure java implementation fixed the issue, at the cost of performance.

*Explanation*:

I've spent the past 3 days banging my head to the wall with an SQLite exception saying "SQL logic error or missing database". I won't comment on the exception text that includes two  possible, *different* errors without saying which could be the cause. I won't comment either on the fact that none of the two errors mentioned in the exception text was the cause of the issue.

Facts:

- SQLite exception stating "*SQL logic error or missing database*"
- Using [jsqlitejdbc](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) v056
- The driver is able to create tables
- The driver is able to select information from tables
- The database file is not corrupted, ie. it is possible to open it with a sqlite client and insert data to the tables
- **The driver is unable to insert data into tables**

What solved my issue is replace `sqlitejdbc-v056.jar` which contains native code by `sqlitejdbc-v056-pure.jar` which is a pure-java implementation.

I hope that all the users that had this issue will be able to quickly see this, and not lose 3 days on this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also spend like 4 days, without a clue on sqlitejdbc-v056.jar and so called "logic error or missing database" on my prepstatement. Thanks for your answer. I just used Xerial and it just worked like a charm! Thanks to you!